# Multiline text not getting ellipsized

Tags: ios, multiline, nsattributedstring, text-rendering

I'm trying to draw ellipsized text on multiple lines inside a rectangle.

For `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`, the documentation states

> The line is displayed so that the beginning fits in the container and the missing text at the end of the line is indicated by an ellipsis glyph. Although this mode works for multiline text, it is more often used for single line text.

but with that mode I only get a single line:

[image: With NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail]

However with `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`, I don't get an ellipsis for overlong text:

[image: With NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]

Both pictures use the same code below (red background is the text drawing rectangle) and of course the same rectangle size, so 2 lines should definitely fit.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = <<see above>>;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
NSDictionary* drawingAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:36],
                                   NSFontAttributeName,
                                   paragraphStyle,
                                   NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                   nil];

const CGRect rect = CGRectMake(...);
[@"I do not get ellipsized in any way" drawInRect:rect withAttributes:drawingAttributes];
```

---

Is there a way to combine ellipsizing with multiline rendering, as the documentation says? With a UILabel, I would only have to set the number of lines to something other than 1, but what about text rendering via code?

Comment: I belive multiline means...a scroll bar. And you want 2 line textfield. So you can create two textField, one normal another one truncate tail.

Comment: This is not about a UI control, but about text rendering via code!

Comment: yeah, but the text will be rendered in some UI. And the ONLY UI will show in either of the way. if you have two UIs then this can be done. or probably you need to create a custom UI with this requiremnt.

Comment: Well I'm asking for a way to not have to use custom code (I surely won't write wrapping+ellipsizing code). And I'm rendering to an image, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you are using NSMutableParagraphStyle and drawInRect, probably I'll need more information about the context you are trying to work.

But using this simple technique:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0,0,300,100}];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
label.center = self.view.center;
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:36];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
label.text = @"I do not get ellipsized in any way";

[self.view addSubview:label];
```

You will see the following result:
[image]

My suggestion is to get rid of drawInRect in this case.